# Can a default ignore pattern be applied to PHPCS?

Tags: php

I really like PHPCS, but having to type in `--ignore=vendor` each time is a pain. I've had a good look around but can't find anything on the subject.

I've added the following to my `.bash_profile`, but I was hoping there might be a better idea.

```
alias phpcs="command phpcs --ignore=vendor"
```

Comment: Without duplicating the ruleset or using a build tool, it looks like the `bash alias` option might be the easiest. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest answer is just to use a bash alias. `alias phpcs="command phpcs --ignore=vendor"`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think your choice is great if what you want is to save yourself time. I'll give you a different suggestion.

You can use ant, and make it run phpcs with the options that you want, so you could run just "ant" from the command line.

I also suggest you have a look at phpmd, it's awesome to enforce code quality.

Comment: Not a bad option, but looking to keep away from ant. I'll probably be moving to grunt or gulp in the near future, so something similar there might be an idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you create your own ruleset.xml file, you can set default exclude paths, define your own coding standard rules, and configure all parts of PHP_CodeSniffer. The syntax is documented here: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Annotated-ruleset.xml

The bit you're looking for is the `exclude-pattern` tag.

It's a good idea to commit the ruleset.xml file into the project's repository directly so all developers can use it. Then each developer can run `phpcs --standard=/path/to/ruleset.xml /path/to/code` or, from the project's root directory `phpcs --standard=ruleset.xml .` to use relative paths.

Comment: Combine this with the `phpcs --config-set default_standard` command and it might work. But at the moment, the `bash alias` is still my easiest option.